# DataBase Access Problem in Android1.6

Tags: android, sqlite

I m accessing `SQLite databse` from the following location`/data/data/files/examples/search.sqlite` it works fine in Samsung Tablet but when i run the same code in android 1.6 it throws the error.
  `06-23 09:06:24.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(221): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File  /data/data/files/examples/search.sqlite contains a path separator`
 I was wonder why this error throws in `android 1.6` not in samsung Galaxy tab i.e., `android 2.2`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332328/sqliteopenhelper-problem-with-fully-qualified-db-path-name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `/data/data/files/examples/` directory on any Android device that I am aware of. Please use a real directory, one that is actually possible. For example, [`getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) will return a valid path to a SQLite database file.