# GreenDao database is not removed on app uninstall

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I have an Android app that uses GreenDao for persistence.

I am under the impression that uninstalling the app from a device should remove any data files under the path /data/data/[package name]/databases, which is where GreenDao stores its data by default ([Where is my database file created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386066/where-is-created-my-database-file))

Given I have closed my app to ensure it is not running and uninstall the app, when I reinstall the app and run it, then I would expect there to be no data from previous sessions stored.

However, the specific user data I have stored in this previous session remains available when I perform a getRowById request to the relevant UserDao after the clean install.

Why does this data persist after uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `android:allowBackup`  value in android manifest, if the value is set to true then android will backup the db, and will persist it after uninstall.