# No such table found- i created table using one application and i tried retrieve values from table using another application

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi i used this coding to create table and insert the data into the table. and i used another application to get the value from the same table it shows no such table found please anyone can help..

```
    try{
                   Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this, "In try ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                   db = openOrCreateDatabase( "Emergency.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null );

                   String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists userinformation (mail VARCHAR(255),pass VARCHAR(255))";
                   db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

                   String qu="select * from userinformation";
                   c=db.rawQuery(qu,null);

                   int count = c.getCount();

                   String[] values = new String[count + 1];
                   int i = 0;
                   for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                       values[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mail"));
                       Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this, values[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       i++;
                    }  


                   i=0;
                   if(count==0)
                   {
                   String    Query =    "insert into userinformation (mail,pass) values ('"+ mailuser+ "','" + password + "')";
                   db.execSQL(Query);
                   Toast.makeText(FiveActivity.this,"Values Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
```

Comment: sorry you can not access database from other application because its databases are stored in application storage under package directory.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053809/share-sqlite-database-between-2-android-apps)

Other options
 1. ContentProviders
 2. IPC

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229616/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry you can not access database from other application because its databases are stored in application storage under package directory.

If you want to access database from multiple application you need to create database on sdcard.
Follow the stpes.

First you have to specify the path of the sdcard. You can do that by creating a string like this:

```
public static final String  DATABASE_FILE_PATH = "/sdcard";
```

But for you should call

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to get the root path to the SD card and use that to create the database. After that you create the database as you want. Here is an example

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    public static final String DATABASE_FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/directorynameWhereYouWantTocreateDatabase";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    public static final String TRACKS_TABLE = "tracks";
    public static final String TRACK_INFO_TABLE = "track_info";

    private static final String TRACKS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table " + TRACKS_TABLE
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, description text null, created_at date not null);";

    private static final String TRACK_INFO_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TRACK_INFO_TABLE
            + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, track_id integer not null, latitude real not null, longitude real not null, altitude real not null, created_at date not null);";

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseHelper() {
        try {
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error -- " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            // error means tables does not exits
            createTables();
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    private void createTables() {
        database.execSQL(TRACKS_TABLE_CREATE);
        database.execSQL(TRACK_INFO_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }

}

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        return database;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return database;
    }
}
```

And in the end you have to set permission in manifest like this: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Good luck :)

Comment: opening database is creating database itself. It will create and open db if not exists and open if already exists

Comment: Thank you...here what is DButil

Comment: Is is my custom class to handle db close

Comment: what should it contain

Answer (score 0):

Databases are specific to the application. When you access a database according to its name (like you did here with "Emergency.db"), the DB file is actually created within the application's "App Data" storage space. This means that this DB is hidden to other applications.

If you want to pass data between apps, use the [usual methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#IPC).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? If you want to get anything from the other app, use `intents`. Request(with `startActivityForResult`) the other app to give anything, as a result other app would respond and give a result(with `setResult`). And use that result in `onActivityResult`. I would have chosen this kind of approach.