# Android SQLite Database Helper Instance

Tags: android, android-sqlite, instance

In a previous article there is a way to create a single instance of my SQLiteDatabse and then simply reference it throughout my App.  I can not figure how to tell it where my database is.  Since my database is written to the SDCard, there has got to be a way to tell it which database it should use right?  Here is the code below:

```
    public class DatabaseManager {

    private int mOpenCounter;

    private static DatabaseManager instance;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseManager();
            mDatabaseHelper = helper;
        }
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(DatabaseManager.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " is not initialized, call initializeInstance(..) method first.");
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        mOpenCounter++;
        if(mOpenCounter == 1) {
            // Opening new database
            mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }

    public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
        mOpenCounter--;
        if(mOpenCounter == 0) {
            // Closing database
            mDatabase.close();

        }
    }

}
```

My actual database is called FooBase.db

```
static File directoryPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyApp/database");
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to mention the path of the database explicitly.

All the android apps by default store their database(s) in the location
`/data/data/packageName/`

[SQLiteOpenHelper - creating database on SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229450/sqliteopenhelper-creating-database-on-sd-card)

[How to store sqlite database directly on sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373863/how-to-store-sqlite-database-directly-on-sdcard)

The [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler))

Comment: Thank you but in this case the database will become at at least 13mb or more, so I wanted to be sure there is plenty of space by writing it to the SDCard along with other files as part of the app.  So with that, I still must designate the above

Comment: additionally, there still has to be a way to tell this which database to open.  What if you have many?

Comment: Ok... now thats a different case I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this has nothing to do with my question.  I already have a working database and have already created it.  I ran into Asynctask problems where the database would be closed while trying to read it.  SO I am adding the code above so that I can properly reference one single instance.  What the code above is missing, is the database name and location.  Otherwise, what is the instance a reference to.

Comment: the solution are there in the answers of the links I provided. all you need to do add the path in the `onCreate()` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and create a directory in the SD card and use it. Additionally you will need READ/Write permission for the SD Card.