# How to understand type "Context"?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

```
private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    OpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}}
```

I cannot understand the meaning of type `Context`. I read the manual but can not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is an interface!

According to source code:

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class >whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/content/Context.java#Context for the best understanding

Answer (score 0):

`Context` refers to the context of the activity where the database object is created.

Let `SampleClass` be the activity in which you want to access the database.

SampleClass.this will be the argument to that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Context`, provided to `SQLiteOpenHelper` is used (among other) to obtain database path, calling

```
context.getDatabasePath();
```

So, the only reason to pass some custom context implementation is to override database location, as described in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168969/716075