# How can i store or get sqlite database in android other then Databases default location

Tags: java, android, database

I am trying to access the sqlite database from other location then android's default location which is **/data/data/packname/databases/**

Comment: You cannot do this for security reasons.

Comment: How it could be for security reason, i want to use some other location then default location but in same application,

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand your question at first.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with a database that is not in the default path, simply use [`ContextWrapper#openOrCreateDatabase()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29). (Understand that you cannot use the SQLiteOpenHelper class when you do this.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you can implement your own `context` class with overritten `getDatabasePath()` that points to you own directory.

Normal android apps have their local database files relative to the app folder. By using a customer context with overritten ´getDatabasePath()´ the database is now relative to a different directory on the sd card.

For details and code sample see [sqliteopenhelper-with-fully-qualified-db-path-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332328/sqliteopenhelper-problem-with-fully-qualified-db-path-name/9168969#9168969)