# how to fetch data from database sored in assets folder in android

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

I had created my database using SQLite database browser and stored it in to assets folder in my project. When I'm trying to fetch data from that folder its showing error

```
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pocketdr/com.example.pocketdr.PocketDoc}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error: , while compiling: /data/data/com.example.pocketdr/databases/Diseases.db/Diseaseslist/
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error: , while compiling: /data/data/com.example.pocketdr/databases/Diseases.db/Diseaseslist/
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:73)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1442)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at com.example.pocketdr.Database.getSymptom(Database.java:215)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at com.example.pocketdr.PocketDoc.onCreate(PocketDoc.java:60)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
03-28 01:07:39.840: E/AndroidRuntime(7390):     ... 11 more
```

DATABASE Helper CLASS

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
 private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.pocketdr/databases/";
private static final String DB_NAME = "Diseases.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
public static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "Diseaseslist";
private static final String  _ID="id";
public static final String COLUMN_1_NAME = "Name";
private static final String COLUMN_2_Symptom="Symptom";
private static final String COLUMN_3_Symptom1="Symptom1";
private static final String COLUMN_4_Symptom2="Symptom2";
private static final String COLUMN_5_Symptom3="Symptom3";
private static final String COLUMN_6_Discription="Discription";
private static final String COLUMN_7_Precaution="Precaution";
String[] str,str1,str2;



private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBInstance ;
private final Context myContext;
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION_NUMBER);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
 {

     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

     if(dbExist){
     //do nothing - database already exist
     }else{

     //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
     //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
     this.getReadableDatabase();

     try {

     copyDataBase();

     } catch (IOException e) {

     throw new Error("Error copying database");

     }
     }

     }

     /**
       * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
       * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
       */
     private boolean checkDataBase(){

     SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

     try{
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

     }catch(SQLiteException e){

     //database does't exist yet.

     }

     if(checkDB != null){

     checkDB.close();

     }

     return checkDB != null ? true : false;
     }

     /**
       * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
       * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
       * This is done by transfering bytestream.
       * */
     private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

     //Open your local db as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

     // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

     //Open the empty db as the output stream
     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
     myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }

     //Close the streams
     myOutput.flush();
     myOutput.close();
     myInput.close();

     }

     public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

     //Open the database
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     sqliteDBInstance = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

     }

     @Override
     public synchronized void close() {

     if(sqliteDBInstance != null)
     sqliteDBInstance.close();

     super.close();

     }


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBInstance) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    public long insertDiseases(String Name,String Symptom,String Symptom1,String Symptom2,String Symptom3,String Description, String Precaution)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_1_NAME, Name);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_2_Symptom, Symptom);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_3_Symptom1, Symptom1);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_4_Symptom2, Symptom2);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_5_Symptom3, Symptom3);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_6_Discription, Description);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_7_Precaution, Precaution);
        Log.i(this.toString() + " - insertCountry", "Inserting: " + Name);
        return this.sqliteDBInstance.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public boolean removeDiseases(String Name)
    {
        int result = this.sqliteDBInstance.delete(DB_TABLE_NAME, "Name='" + Name + "'", null);

        if(result > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public long updateCountry(String oldName, String newName)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_1_NAME, newName);
        return this.sqliteDBInstance.update(DB_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "Name='" + oldName + "'", null);
    }

    public String[] getSymptom()
    {
        String myPath1 = DB_PATH + DB_NAME+"/"+DB_TABLE_NAME+"/" ;

    Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance.rawQuery(myPath1, new String[]{COLUMN_2_Symptom});//query(myPath1, new String[] {COLUMN_2_Symptom}, null, null, null, null, null);
 Log.i(COLUMN_2_Symptom, "Symptom"+cursor);
        if(cursor.getCount() >0)
        {
             str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int i = 0;

            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                 str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_2_Symptom));
                 i++;
             }

            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            return new String[] {};
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your database helper??

Comment: If you are using an older Android version (<= Android 2.2), there was a known issue with full path (check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332328/sqliteopenhelper-problem-with-fully-qualified-db-path-name). What version are you using? P.S. your variable `String myPath1 = ...` might be wrong.

Comment: i'm using Android 2.3.5 version

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String[] getSymptom()
    {
        String myPath1 = DB_PATH + DB_NAME+"/"+DB_TABLE_NAME+"/" ;

    Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance.rawQuery(myPath1, new String[]{COLUMN_2_Symptom});
    }
```

Your String myPath1 should contain a valid SQLite Query not the path to the database table.

Try something like "Select * from your_tablename Where column_name = value"

or you can use query instead of rawQuery. Refer [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-sqlite-query-example-selection.html)