# How to access shared prefrence data of other app in android?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have two app one app is named as "A" and another app named as "B" ,scenario is something like that app B is integrated in app A and App B has a class called `CLoginSessionManagement` which contain code for user data stored in that class.What I want in App "A" to access user data from `CLoginSessionManagement` and make condition if user is login or not. How can I do that?

Code for CLoginSessionManagement:

```
public class CLoginSessionManagement {
    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String s_szKEY_MOBILE = "agentcode";
    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String s_szKEY_PASSWORD = "pin";
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String s_szPREF_NAME = "LoginData";
    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String s_szIS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    private final SharedPreferences m_LOGIN_PREF;
    private final Editor m_EDITOR;
    private final Context m_CONTEXT;


    // Constructor
    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    public CLoginSessionManagement(Context m_CONTEXT) {
        this.m_CONTEXT = m_CONTEXT;
        m_LOGIN_PREF = m_CONTEXT.getSharedPreferences(s_szPREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        m_EDITOR = m_LOGIN_PREF.edit();
    }


    // Registeration Session Management....
    public void setLoginData(String mobile, String pin) {
        m_EDITOR.putBoolean(s_szIS_LOGIN, true);
        m_EDITOR.putString(s_szKEY_MOBILE, mobile);
        m_EDITOR.putString(s_szKEY_PASSWORD, pin);
        m_EDITOR.commit();
    }

    /**
     * checkLogin() session wil check user Login status
     * If false it will redirect user to Login page
     * Else won't do anything
     */
    public boolean checkLogin() {
        if (!isLogin()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(m_CONTEXT, CMainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            m_CONTEXT.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get stored Login session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getLoginDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        // user name
        user.put(s_szKEY_MOBILE, m_LOGIN_PREF.getString(s_szKEY_MOBILE, null));
        // user email id
        user.put(s_szKEY_PASSWORD, m_LOGIN_PREF.getString(s_szKEY_PASSWORD, null));
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    public boolean isLogin() {
        return m_LOGIN_PREF.getBoolean(s_szIS_LOGIN, false);
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        m_EDITOR.clear();
        m_EDITOR.commit();
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") final AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) m_CONTEXT;
        Intent i = new Intent(m_CONTEXT, CLoginScreen.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        m_CONTEXT.startActivity(i);
        ((AppCompatActivity) m_CONTEXT).finish();

    }
}

m_oLoginSession = new CLoginSessionManagement(CLoginScreen.this);// object creatiion of Login session.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have a look to android dev docs and it states that SharedPreferences is private to your application. You may try content provider:

> Android provides a way for you to expose even your private data to other applications — with a content provider.

Ref links:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

Since SharedPreferences are protected by android-os you have to store and load the content at a file directory that both apps can read/write.

The trick to do this replace the android-sandbox `Context` with your own code.

Instead of calling `MyActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(...)` you use

```
Context context = new PublicPreferencesContext(MyActivity.this);
context.getSharedPreferences(...);
```

Here is where all the magic happens:

```
class PublicPreferencesContext extends ContextWrapper {
    public PublicPreferencesContext(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    // overwrite the shared-preferences specific functions here
    // getSharedPreferences, ...
}
```

I have done something similar to [change the location where the database is stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332328/sqliteopenhelper-problem-with-fully-qualified-db-path-name/9168969#9168969) wich works very well. Doing this whith SharedPreferences should work as well.

If this works for you please let us know and give us the complete sourcecode for `PublicPreferencesContext`

Answer (score -1):

`SharedPreferences` only exist itself package
 You can try learn ：

1. `content provider`
2. `aidl （IPC）`