# Android SQLite Read Database from External Storage Folder

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently, I am developing an Android application where my requirement is to read SQLite db from a fixed location in **External Location**. But I am not unable to open the database. The code I am trying is below:

**DatabaseHelper:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    //private static final String DB_NAME = "MedRec.db";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "MedRec";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        //super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);

        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EMIS/MedRec", null, 1);
        //super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/EMIS/" + DB_NAME, null, 1);

        Log.d("DB_PATH:", context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/EMIS/" + DB_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
    {
        Log.d("CREATING TABLE :", "SUCCESS");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,int oldVersion,int newVersion)
    {

        Log.d("UPGRADING TABLE :", "SUCCESS");

        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

**PatientDataSource:**

```
package com.medrecordapp.main.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import com.medrecordapp.main.model.Patient;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PatientDataSource
{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public static final String TABLE_PATIENT = "Patient";

    public final static String ID                = "_id";
    public final static String PATIENT_ID        = "PatientID";
    public final static String NHS_NUMBER        = "NHSNumber";
    public final static String FIRST_NAME        = "FirstName";
    public final static String LAST_NAME         = "LastName";
    public final static String CATEGORY          = "category";
    public final static String PHONE_1           = "phone1";
    public final static String PHONE_2           = "phone2";
    public final static String PHOTO_FILE        = "photofile";
    public final static String PROFESSION        = "profession";
    public final static String STREET            = "Street";
    public final static String VILLAGE           = "Village";
    public final static String TOWN              = "Town";
    public final static String COUNTRY           = "County";
    public final static String POST_CODE         = "PostCode";
    public final static String COMMENT           = "comment";
    public final static String E1                = "E1";
    public final static String E2                = "E2";
    public final static String E3                = "E3";
    public final static String E4                = "E4";
    public final static String E5                = "E5";
    public final static String UPD_DATE          = "upddate";

    public PatientDataSource(Context context)
    {
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
        ///dbHelper.openDataBase();
        //dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public long addPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        open();

        ContentValues patientValue = new ContentValues();

        patientValue.put(PATIENT_ID, patient.getPatientId());
        patientValue.put(NHS_NUMBER, patient.getNhsNumber());
        patientValue.put(FIRST_NAME, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(LAST_NAME, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(CATEGORY, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(PHONE_1, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(PHONE_2, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(PHOTO_FILE, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(PROFESSION, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(STREET, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(VILLAGE, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(TOWN, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(COUNTRY, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(POST_CODE, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(COMMENT, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(E1, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(E2, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(E3, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(E4, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(E5, patient.getFirstName());
        patientValue.put(UPD_DATE, patient.getFirstName());

        long insertId = database.insert(TABLE_PATIENT,null,patientValue);

        Log.d("RESULT :", insertId + "");

        close();

        return insertId;
    }

    public ArrayList<Patient> loadPatient()
    {
        open();

        ArrayList<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM Patient " , null );

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Patient patient = new Patient(
                                            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))   ,  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PatientID")),  cursor.getString(2),  cursor.getString(3),
                                            cursor.getString(4),  cursor.getString(5),  cursor.getString(6),  cursor.getString(6),
                                            cursor.getString(7),  cursor.getString(8),  cursor.getString(9),  cursor.getString(10),
                                            cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13), cursor.getString(14),
                                            cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18),
                                            cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20), cursor.getString(21)
                                         );

            patientList.add(patient);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();

        close();

        return patientList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Patient> loadPatient(String patientId)
    {
        open();

        ArrayList<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE _id = ?" , new String[]{ patientId } );

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Patient patient = new Patient(
                                                cursor.getInt(0)   ,  cursor.getString(1),  cursor.getString(2),  cursor.getString(3),
                                                cursor.getString(4),  cursor.getString(5),  cursor.getString(6),  cursor.getString(6),
                                                cursor.getString(7),  cursor.getString(8),  cursor.getString(9),  cursor.getString(10),
                                                cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13), cursor.getString(14),
                                                cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18),
                                                cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20), cursor.getString(21)
                                         );

            patientList.add(patient);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();

        close();

        return patientList;
    }

    /*public void updateFavorites(Favorites favoritesInfo,String id)
    {
        open();

        ContentValues favoritesInfoValues = new ContentValues();

        String strFilter = "id = " + id;

        favoritesInfoValues.put(ID, favoritesInfo.getFavoritesId());
        favoritesInfoValues.put(JOKES_ID, favoritesInfo.getJokesId());

        //Update using the SQLite update function.
        database.update(TABLE_FAVORITES, favoritesInfoValues, strFilter, null);

        //Close the opened database connection
        close();
    }*/

    public boolean deletePatient(String id)
    {
        open();

        String strFilter = "_id =" + id;

        boolean res = database.delete(TABLE_PATIENT, strFilter , null) > 0;

        close();

        return res;
    }
}
```

**Manifest Permissions:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But what I am getting is the following exceptions:

```
    10-25 12:49:25.838  30502-30502/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
10-25 12:49:25.838  30502-30502/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:31278: (2) open(/storage/emulated/0/EMIS/MedRec) -
10-25 12:49:25.838  30502-30502/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteConnection﹕ DB info: sqlite3_open_v2, path: /storage/emulated/0/EMIS/MedRec, flag: 6, ret: 14
10-25 12:49:25.838  30502-30502/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteConnection﹕ DB info: errno = 2, errno message = No such file or directory
10-25 12:49:25.839  30502-30502/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/EMIS/MedRec'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:237)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:221)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:468)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:182)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:876)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:856)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:754)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:579)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.medrecordapp.main.database.PatientDataSource.open(PatientDataSource.java:53)
            at com.medrecordapp.main.database.PatientDataSource.loadPatient(PatientDataSource.java:100)
            at com.medrecordapp.main.activity.PatientListActivity.onCreate(PatientListActivity.java:90)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
10-25 12:49:25.840  30502-30502/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.medrecodapp.main.database, PID: 30502
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medrecodapp.main.database/com.medrecordapp.main.activity.PatientListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:237)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:221)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:468)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:182)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:876)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:856)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:754)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:579)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.medrecordapp.main.database.PatientDataSource.open(PatientDataSource.java:53)
            at com.medrecordapp.main.database.PatientDataSource.loadPatient(PatientDataSource.java:100)
            at com.medrecordapp.main.activity.PatientListActivity.onCreate(PatientListActivity.java:90)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
```

The file has bee put inside the following folder :

[image]

[image]

One last thing I would like to mention is that I am testing this on HTC 10 which does not have any External storage, but emulated storage. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where is your Create table Query?

Comment: Do i have to create them again, are'nt they already in the MedRecord.db?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from [@k3b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519334/k3b) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168969/4758255):

You can use the **SQLiteOpenHelper** with a custom path if you provide a custom **ContextClass** and if you have write access to the target directory.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    .....

  DatabaseHelper(final Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(new DatabaseContext(context), databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

And here is the custom DatabaseContext class that does all the magic:

```
class DatabaseContext extends ContextWrapper {

  private static final String DEBUG_CONTEXT = "DatabaseContext";

  public DatabaseContext(Context base) {
    super(base);
  }

  @Override
  public File getDatabasePath(String name)  {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
    String dbfile = sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+ "databases" + File.separator + name;
    if (!dbfile.endsWith(".db")) {
      dbfile += ".db" ;
    }

    File result = new File(dbfile);

    if (!result.getParentFile().exists()) {
      result.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }

    if (Log.isLoggable(DEBUG_CONTEXT, Log.WARN)) {
      Log.w(DEBUG_CONTEXT, "getDatabasePath(" + name + ") = " + result.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    return result;
  }

  /* this version is called for android devices >= api-11. thank to @damccull for fixing this. */
  @Override
  public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    return openOrCreateDatabase(name,mode, factory);
  }

  /* this version is called for android devices < api-11 */
  @Override
  public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
    SQLiteDatabase result = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePath(name), null);
    // SQLiteDatabase result = super.openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory);
    if (Log.isLoggable(DEBUG_CONTEXT, Log.WARN)) {
      Log.w(DEBUG_CONTEXT, "openOrCreateDatabase(" + name + ",,) = " + result.getPath());
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

How does this work:

Normal android apps have their local database files relative to the app folder. By using a customer context with overwritten `getDatabasePath()` the database is now relative to a different directory on the sd card.

Comment: How can i give write access to the given directory?

Comment: I have done the way you did. But still getting this thing:

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: 10-25 13:39:39.304  25082-25082/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteConnection﹕ DB info: sqlite3_open_v2, path: /storage/emulated/0/EMIS/MedRec.db, flag: 6, ret: 14
10-25 13:39:39.304  25082-25082/com.medrecodapp.main.database E/SQLiteConnection﹕ DB info: errno = 13, errno message = Permission denied

Comment: I guess its permission related issue.

Comment: Did you run the apps in > Android  6.0? Then you need to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: After adding Runtime permissions i am now getting Screen Overlay Detected error issue. Any idea. Btw the above way worked on other Marshmallow device

Comment: is  `the above way worked on other Marshmallow device`  means that not working for all marshmallow devices?.  Is this `Screen Overlay Detected error issue` to read database issue?

Comment: No actually it was a issue due to ES File Explorer. After uninstalling it, works perfectly. Also the other device also worked first in Marshmallow too

Comment: Great, glad it works for you..:)

Comment: I got no such table error in android 5.0, but android 9 is ok. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

First think is that if you are using above marshmallow (ANDROID 6.0) os then you need to take run time permission from user for access external storage device even if you mentioned it in manifest file. So take care about this. After that, we can check using following code. I am mentioning only file pick code and write it into database. You should call intent for select file.

```
 String yourDatabaseLocation = "/data/data/yourPackageName/databases/YourdaatabaseName.db";
        String stringArray[] = filePath.split(":");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
            String selectedFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + stringArray[1];
            File file = new File(selectedFile);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                os = new FileOutputStream(yourDatabaseLocation);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((int length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                fis.close();
```

This block will help you for insert your database which is present on external storage to your current database. Database structure should be same for to do this.

Comment: @ Kailas Bhakade -  I think we need permission to access this db file we can not access this db directly..

Comment: @AnkushGuhe- Yes you are right. But if you are using emulator then does not need to take any permission. Because emulator is already rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't You try to copy your db file to where it normally should be? The path may probably look like this:

```
String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "//databases//" + DbOpenHelper.DB_NAME;
```

Comment: Client does not want that way. I have already done that worked successfully. But clients requirement is that way.