# Creating Database from SD card using Android Jellybean

Tags: android, import, sqliteopenhelper

Can anyone can create a database from SD card using Jellybean API 18?

but i should call this path like **`/storage/sdcard1`**. there are some many tutorials but does not work. Actually im using SQLiteOpenHelper.[Some people says that if you create database from SD card, you dont need SQLiteOpenHelper.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333248/9623243)

Comment: What you need is just to change the path of your default SD card creation.

Comment: yes like File file = new File("/storage/sdcard1"); instead of Environment.etc

Comment: No, not like that, there is a different way of giving for Database.

Comment: do you have a source code or link tutorial?

Comment: Check out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You just have to modify the constructor in order to change it's path:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/mydb.db", null, 0);
    }
}
```

You can also get the folder string path and change it accordingly as you require. **Ex:** "/storage/emulated/0/folder/mydb.db"

Don't forget to add **Write and Read Storage Permissions**.

Try it, Hope it's helpful.

Comment: @KageRyu, No idea, I havn't tried that, only a trial will tell.